# TFS: Rolling back package references

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I recently committed a changeset which added references to `Castle.Core.4.2.1` and `Moq.4.7.145`. I would like to roll back this changeset.

My workspace contains the latest source code from source control, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

On my local workspace, the packages are also there:

[image]

Using Visual Studio, I navigated to Source Control Explorer, right-clicked on `Castle.Core.4.2.1`, selected "Rollback...", and entered the number of the changeset in which I first added the reference.

[image]

Immediately I saw the following warnings:

[image]

On my local workspace, `Castle.Core.4.2.1` can no longer be found:

[image]

I am unable to commit a rollback of the changeset because of the warnings that you saw -- my local copy of `Castle.Core.4.2.1` was deleted immediately after I performed a rollback.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the warnings is because you applied Check-in policy for this team project. Try to go to Settings -- Source Control -- Check-in Policy to disable the policy:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I cannot disable that policy due to lack of administrative rights in my organisation. I will mark your answer as accepted nonetheless.